# ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (10000)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to generate fake data that I will use in a censored regression model. Where X is uniformly distributed. U is normally distributed. And n = 10,000.

I used the code below and when I run it I get the error message.

```
def gen_q2_data(n=10000):
    data = pd.DataFrame()
    data['X'] = rng.uniform(-1.5, 1.5, n)
    data['U'] = rng.normal(0, np.sqrt(2), n)
    y_star = 0.5 + 2 * data['X'] - data['U']
    data['y'] = np.where(y_star > .5)
    return data


data_q2 = gen_q2_data.head()
```

I am getting a `ValueError`:.

> ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (10000)

Comment: I would encourage you to ensure that the size argument `n` is being correctly interpreted, by replacing the arguments with `uniform(-1.5, 1.5, size=n)` and `normal(0, np.sqrt(2), size=n)`

Comment: Did you mean `data['y'] = np.where(y_star > .5, 1, 0)`? `np.where` alone is not going to produce results as expected because it's going to return a tuple without `True` `False` values. *Note this also assumes your actual code _calls_ the function `data_q2 = gen_q2_data().head()`

Comment: @dsillman2000 I did that but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @HenryEcker If I use ```data['y'] = np.where(y_star > .5, 1, 0) would that make the values of y be equal to .5, 1, and 0?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do but yes. If `y_star > .5` is `True` you get `1` in column `y` else you get `0` in column `y`. You could naturally adjust to use whatever values you want.

Comment: @HenryEcker I just tried your suggestion. It worked. I still have one question: Does the code mean that for y_star greater than .5, make y=1 and 0 otherwise?

Comment: Yes. That is what `np.where(y_star > .5, 1, 0)` means.

Comment: @HenryEcker thank you. I'm sure I will have more questions. Looking forward to getting more answers from you lol.

Comment: @dsillman2000 thank you. I'm sure I will have more questions. Looking forward to getting more answers from you lol.